# SQL Server : alter stored procedure to accept parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

`Employee` table

[image: Employee Table]

Write a SQL statement that would alter the below-mentioned pre-existing stored procedure to accomplish the following:

- allow for a parameter to be supplied containing a manager's `Emp_ID`
- use the supplied parameter to qualify the `Emp_ID` in the query
- assign the parameter a value of zero if no parameter value is supplied
- rewrite the result statement as a `JOIN` that includes the Manager's last name
- ensure the results are displayed as follows:

  ```
  Manager's Last Name
  Employee's Last Name
  Employees Hire Date
  ```
- order the results of the query by the Manager's last name, the most recent hires and the Employee's last name

This is the pre-existing stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetEmployeeNm 
AS
   SELECT  
       Last_Nm, Hire_Dt
   FROM 
       dbo.Employee
   WHERE 
       Mgr_ID IN (SELECT Emp_ID 
                  FROM dbo.Employee 
                  WHERE Emp_ID = 12345)
```

Is there anyone who knows how to correctly ALTER this stored procedure?

This is what I tried:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetEmployeeNm (@Emp_ID INT = 0) 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        m.Last_Nm AS Manager's Last Name, 
        e.Last_Nm AS Employee's Last Name, 
        e.Hire_Dt AS Employee's Hire Date
    FROM
        Employee  e
    INNER JOIN 
        Employee m ON e.Emp_ID = m.Mgr_ID
    WHERE 
        e.Emp_ID = 12345
    ORDER BY 
        (m.Last_Nm, e.Hire_Dt, e.Last_Nm) DESC
END
```

Comment: At a first glance, it looks like you need to change `WHERE e.Emp_ID = 12345` to `WHERE e.Emp_ID = @Emp_ID`.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetEmployeeNm 
    @Emp_ID INT = 0 
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        m.Last_Nm AS 'Manager''s Last Name', 
        e.Last_Nm AS 'Employee''s Last Name', 
        e.Hire_Dt AS 'Employee''s Hire Date'
    FROM 
        Employee  e
    INNER JOIN 
        Employee m ON e.Emp_ID = m.Mgr_ID
    WHERE 
        e.Emp_ID = @Emp_ID
    ORDER BY 
        (m.Last_Nm, e.Hire_Dt, e.Last_Nm) DESC
END
GO
```

Use

```
EXEC dbo.sp_GetEmployeeNm 12345
```

Comment: And you need to put those column aliases into double quotes!! `m.Last_Nm AS "Manager's Last Name", ....`